# Elements in flexbox don't move, when I shrink the size of my window

Tags: html, css

I want that the div panel_pricing-table become a flexbox so that all elements in it stay in this box also when I make my window smaller. My problem is that the elements in the flexbox won't shrink, if I make my browser window smaller. The mistake is in CSS but I don't find it. Can you help me pls?
`

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #3a86ff;
    
}

.panel_pricing-table{
width:80%;
margin: 0 auto;
 display :flex;
  transform: translateY(70%);
 background-color: aliceblue;
 min-width: 40px;
 max-width: 34200px;

}
```

`

`

```
  <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
           name="viewport"
           content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Price Tiers</title>
        <link
           rel="stylesheet"
           href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
     </head>

     <body>
        <div class="panel_pricing-table">
           <div class="pricing-plan">
              <img src="icons/icon1.png" alt="" class="pricing-img" />
              <h2 class="pricing-header">Personal</h2>
              <ul class="pricing-features">
                 <li class="pricing-features-item">Custom domains</li>
                 <li class="pricing-features-item">
                    Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity
                 </li>
              </ul>
              <span class="pricing-price">Free</span>
              <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Sign up</a>
           </div>

           <div class="pricing-plan">
              <img src="icons/icon2.png" alt="" class="pricing-img" />
              <h2 class="pricing-header">Small team</h2>
              <ul class="pricing-features">
                 <li class="pricing-features-item">Never sleeps</li>
                 <li class="pricing-features-item">
                    Multiple workers for more powerful apps
                 </li>
              </ul>
              <span class="pricing-price">$150</span>
              <a href="#/" class="pricing-button is-featured">Free trial</a>
           </div>

           <div class="pricing-plan">
              <img src="icons/icon3.png" alt="" class="pricing-img" />
              <h2 class="pricing-header">Enterprise</h2>
              <ul class="pricing-features">
                 <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
                 <li class="pricing-features-item">
                    Simple horizontal scalability
                 </li>
              </ul>
              <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
              <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit it to this code:

```css
.panel_pricing-table{
 width:90%;
 margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: Alice blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css you can use the overflow property. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```
overflow: scroll;
overflow: hidden;
```

A couple of options.